# Profiling in go

Tags: performance, go

What's the best way to get profiling information about my go program?  I've seen references to pprof, but documentation seems scarce compared to other areas of Go.

Comment: What type of problem are you trying to solve? The advice that that might be useful to a programmer writing software to do matrix multiplication is not the same as the advice you give to a programmer writing a database.

Comment: I'm tinkering with a proxy for redis to do connection pooling and consistent hashing.  It should be pretty light weight, but I'm spiking the CPU when I really slam it.  I want to see where the CPU is spending all that time.  I suspect it has to do with my command parsing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `6prof` [command](http://golang.org/cmd/prof/). Note that it's for all architectures, despite its name.

> For reasons of disambiguation it is installed as 6prof although it also serves as an 8prof and a 5prof.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.  Unfortunately, it causes any application I attach it to to crash horribly, but at least I know where to look.  Thanks!